# ngx-image-cropper in angular, ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject()

Tags: angular, forms, ngx-image-cropper

I am developing a registration form. In this form I ask a photo to the user. In order to respect a precise format, I want to propose a tool to resize directly the user's picture. So I started with ngx-image-cropper which seems to be very useful and functional. The problem is that after following the tutorial, I have an error that I can't solve : ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203.

here is my code :

TS

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ImageCroppedEvent} from "ngx-image-cropper";

export class AdhesionFormComponent{
  
  imageChangedEvent: any = '';
  croppedImage: any = '';

  constructor() { }

  fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = event;
  }
  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
  }
  imageLoaded() {
    // show cropper
  }
  cropperReady() {
    // cropper ready
  }
  loadImageFailed() {
    alert("une erreure s'est produite.")
  }
```

HTML

```
      <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />

      <image-cropper
        [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
        [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
        [aspectRatio]="4 / 3"
        [resizeToWidth]="128"
        format="png"
        (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
        (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
        (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
        (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
      ></image-cropper>

      <img [src]="croppedImage" />
```

i was expecting the ngx-image-cropper work as in the tutorial

Comment: most of the times this means that an inject() function is called outside of the constructor. I don't see that in your code here. Could you provide an sample of where the error occurs

Comment: Here full error message :
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
RuntimeError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:127618:5
injectInjectorOnly@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128161:11
ɵɵinject@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:128172:59
ɵɵdirectiveInject@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:140021:12
ImageCropperComponent_Factory@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:167224:86

Comment: getNodeInjectable@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:48924:38
instantiateAllDirectives@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59804:40
createDirectivesInstances@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59137:27
ɵɵelementStart@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62718:30
AdhesionFormComponent_Template@http://localhost:4200/main.js:290:52

etc...
So i suppose it come frome the ngx-image-cropper, bc i don't use any inject in my code...

Comment: which version of angular are you using? because ngx-image-cropper is only supported on `13+`

Comment: *version `6.0` is only supported on `Angular 13+`

Comment: i'm using version 14.2.6, is 13+ means 13.0.0 until 14.0.0 or 13.0.0 until last version release ?

Comment: just made an stackblitz with `angular 15` seems to work fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhaubv?file=src/main.ts

Comment: have you imported the ImageCropperModule?

Comment: Ye si have, in app.module.ts `import {ImageCropperModule} from "ngx-image-cropper";` nad in the imports. And in my component i import `import {ImageCroppedEvent} from "ngx-image-cropper";` and in the imports.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error in stackblitz so can't help you any further. I don't think your error is related to `ngx-image-cropper` tbh.

Comment: I have recreate a new angular blank project and the ngx-image-cropper work, but i tried this time in the app.components of my project (not in a component), it is still not working but the error isn't exactly the same  :
`ERROR Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor...(same)

    Angular 4 ImageCropperComponent_Factory ngx-image-cropper.mjs:312
    Angular 4 AppComponent_Template app.component.html:52
    Angular 28 4431 main.ts:11
    Webpack 7 core.mjs:9171:22
    Angular 16`

Comment: if the issue indeed comes from the package itself I would suggest making an issue on [their github](https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I reset the node_modules, which corrected the installation and solved the problem